# MVC: How to get the model class from view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a way how to get the model class from view? I have quite complex MVC application where particular views and partial views can be configured via XML configuration file by specifying view name. What I would like to do is to run automatic validation whether views specified in configuration accepts particular classes as models. See example bellow.

Configuration file would look like this:

```
...
<Animals>
    <Animal type="dog" view="DisplayDogName" />
    <Animal type="cat" view="PictureOfTheCat" />
    <Animal type="horse" view="ListOfRacesHorseAttended" />
</Animals>
....
```

Then I would have following controller action:

```
public ActionResult DisplayAnimal(Animal animal)
{
    var viewName = _configManager.GetAnimalViewNameByType(animal.Type);
    return View(viewName, animal);
}
```

Animal class should be a base class for all animals that inherits from it. `_configManager` should be a simple class responsible for loading configuration file and providing its data to the application.

Each view specified in configuration above can specify its model class by `@model ModelClassName` and can access specific model properties then to display them.

My aim is to create validation that would run when application starts from Global.asax. To make sure that application is configured right. That means each configured view will get proper model. It should look somehow like this:

```
public bool ViewAcceptsModelClass(string viewName, Type modelType)
{
   //check whether view specified by viewName accepts modelType as model class
}
```

Comment: This is too broad right now, please add the context of when and how you want to run the validation, with code sample of how you want it to look like.

Comment: @Andrei, thanks for your interest. I have updated my question with simple example. Please let me know if you are missing anything.